# Android Storage Access Framework - ParcelFileDescriptor - creates 0B file when writing file

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Stackoverflow

And thank you so much for reading this question.

I am currently trying to fetch an certain entire directory from my Linux server to

My android phone via sftp.

So far, My code worked fine.

However as soon as I built my app as Signed APK and installed it, Code below does not work as expected.

It doesn't download file from my Linux server but create 0B size files.

```
private void recursiveFolderDownload(String src, DocumentFile pickedDir) throws SftpException, InterruptedException {
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileAndFolderList = channelSftp.ls(src);
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry item : fileAndFolderList) {
        if (!item.getAttrs().isDir()) {
            DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.findFile(item.getFilename());
            if(newFile==null){
                MainActivity.changeLoadingMessage("Fetching "+item.getFilename());
                restoreStatus = "Fetching "+item.getFilename();
                newFile = pickedDir.createFile("",item.getFilename());
                restoringFiles.add(getPathFromUri(newFile.getUri()));
                write(src + "/" + item.getFilename(),newFile.getUri());
            }
            else{
                MainActivity.changeLoadingMessage("Skipping "+item.getFilename());
                restoreStatus = "Skipping "+item.getFilename();
            }
        } else if (!(".".equals(item.getFilename()) || "..".equals(item.getFilename()))) {
            DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.findFile(item.getFilename());
            if(newDir==null){
                newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory(item.getFilename());
            }
            recursiveFolderDownload(src + "/" + item.getFilename(), newDir);
        }
    }
}

private void write(String src, Uri uri) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri,"w");
        if(descriptor!=null) {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            channelSftp.get(src,fos);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Of course I implemented Storage Access Framework by using activity with Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

It's strange that this code works as non-release APK but not as release APK.

Anyway. Thank you so much for reading this question.

Hope I could find answer.

Comment: You might try eliminating the file descriptor bit and just using `openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver`. Beyond that, see if you are logging any crashes from your `catch` block, or see if `channelSftp` is logging anything of note.

Comment: @CommonsWare log says android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Comment: If you have not done so already, try eliminating the file descriptor bit and just using `openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver`. But assuming that your app is using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` directly (and is not working off of some saved `Uri`), then I cannot explain why one build of your app works and another does not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, It works like miracle! Thank you, you're a one true hero